# Override settings within my plugin, use variable or assign to window

Tags: javascript

i have started to code my own plugin's for the company I work for, currently if something want's to change the settings they must create an instance of he plugin and define their settings.

Quick example:

```
var icons = new icons({
  header: "ui-icon-plus",
  activeHeader: "ui-icon-minus"
});
```

Now some of these plugins may become global and always be active, so I was thinking to save needing to create an instance of the plugin, as it will already be there, instead just add a global object which the plugin will check for.

But should I simply do `var plugin_settings = {};` **OR** assign the object to my window `window.plugin_settings = {};`.

Comment: None of them. assign it to *icons* e.g. icons.global_settings

Comment: If you want to do `var plugin_settings = {}` in global scope it is the same as `window.plugin_settings = {}`. Which is terrible idea because it ruins incapsulation and may result in various problems: name conficts, unexpected mutations etc